# Animation displayed well in beamer

Tags: animate

I just want to know how to create nice animation like the one in the video using latex and the animate package, is it possible?

https://youtu.be/-iWgTNbiolw?list=PLHGIkY491Cy1ll7CopaAO_mt_lo_A2L2A&t=387

Comment: This convolution example comes very close the one in the video: https://texample.net/tikz/examples/convolution-of-two-functions